# On Gmail I received an Incoming TLS Encrypted Message. Will my reply be encrypted by default to different email provider?

Tags: email, data-transfer

If I receive an incoming TLS encrypted message from another email provider like outlook/hotmail, will my reply in transit from gmail to outlook/hotmail be encrypted by default as well?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6489/3365

Answer (score 2):

TLS **transport** security between federated servers is fairly common now, however **this is not encrypted email**.

Gmail does not support email encryption.The content of your email is NOT encrypted, nor the replies. The email content is in clear text on all the servers involved.